# Issue while generating PDF from Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, pdf

I have to generate PDf from `UITableView` having multiple sections and rows.

[image]

I have generated the pdf as well but the problem is while creating PDF it is cutting the data of some rows and showing on other page.

So Please suggest any dynamic logic that will help in creating PDf having data on the page without going to other Page .

Also Please find code below which I have used to create PDF.

```
CGRect priorBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
CGSize fittedSize = [self.tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height)];
self.tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, fittedSize.height);

CGRect pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792); // Change this as your need
NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil); {
    for (CGFloat pageOriginY = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height) {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil);

        CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); {
            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY);
            [self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        } CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    }
} UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

self.tableView.bounds = priorBounds; // Reset the tableView


// Use the pdfData to
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//Get the docs directory
NSString *filePathPDF = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.pdf"]; //Add the file name
[pdfData writeToFile:filePathPDF atomically:YES];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please suggest any solution....

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a lot R&D on this, finally I got the solution.
I know this to too late to post answer of above question, but I am posting my solution so it may help someone in future.

The trick which I used to avoid this issue is, Run the loop each section wise and took picture of each dynamic cell.

Then I started combining images of cells by below function,

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
    UIImage *image1 = firstImage;
    UIImage *image2 = secondImage;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
    [image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //set finalImage to IBOulet UIImageView
    return finalImage;
}
```

and to generate combined image, I used below logic. In that I checked the height of combine image, if it is greater than screen size or not.
Below is my whole logic of code,

```
CGRect priorBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    CGSize fittedSize = [self.tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height)];
    self.tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height);

    pdfViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    float sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (int C = 0; C < sections; C++)
    {
        int rows = 0;
        rows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:C];

        for (int I = 0; I < rows; I++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:I inSection:C];

            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.bounds.size, cell.opaque, 0.0);
            [cell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIImage *cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            [pdfViews addObject:cellImage];
        }
    }

    NSArray *pageArray = pdfViews;
    UIImage *pdfFinalImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    UIImage *addOnImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *finalA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int checkHeight;
    checkHeight = 1024;

    for (int Z = 0; Z < [pdfViews count]; Z++)
    {
        if (Z == 0)
        {
            pdfFinalImage = [pageArray objectAtIndex:Z];

        }else if (Z+1 == [pdfViews count])
        {
            addOnImage = [pageArray objectAtIndex:Z];
            if (pdfFinalImage.size.height+addOnImage.size.height > checkHeight)
            {
                [finalA addObject:pdfFinalImage];
                pdfFinalImage = [pageArray objectAtIndex:Z];
                [finalA addObject:pdfFinalImage];

            }else
            {
                pdfFinalImage = [self imageByCombiningImage:pdfFinalImage withImage:addOnImage];
                [finalA addObject:pdfFinalImage];
            }

        }else
        {
            UIImage *heightCheckImage = [pageArray objectAtIndex:Z];
            if (pdfFinalImage.size.height+heightCheckImage.size.height > checkHeight)
            {
                [finalA addObject:pdfFinalImage];
                pdfFinalImage = [pageArray objectAtIndex:Z];
            }else
            {
                addOnImage = [pageArray objectAtIndex:Z];
                pdfFinalImage = [self imageByCombiningImage:pdfFinalImage withImage:addOnImage];
            }
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024), nil);
    for (int IC = 0; IC < [finalA count]; IC++)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        UIImage *mainImage = [finalA objectAtIndex:IC];
        NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mainImage, 0.5);
        CGDataProviderRef dp = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpegData);
        CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dp, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainImage.size.width, mainImage.size.height)];
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    self.tableView.bounds = priorBounds;
    [pdfData writeToFile:tmpPdfPath atomically:YES];
```